# SOAP and PHP SoapClient request error - incorrect or missing id number

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am new to SOAP requests in general and keep getting an error to no avail. Tried connecting via cURL even. I know this isn't the correct way, but wanted to bypass the built in SoapClient function PHP. Below is the code that I am trying.

```
            $client = new SoapClient("http://www.four51.com/services/User.asmx?op=Save");

        $params = array(
            'Users' => array(
                    'UserProperties' => array(
                        'UserInteropID' => '',
                        'CompanyInteropID' => $company,
                        'UserName' => $username,
                        'FirstName' => $first,
                        'LastName' => $last,
                        'PhoneNumber' => '',
                        'Email' => $email,
                        'Password' => $first,
                        'Active' => true,
                        'TermsAccepted' => true,
                    ),
                    'SharedSecret' => $secret
                ),
            );

        $result = $client->Save($params);
        var_dump($result);
```

Sorry if this question is similar to another. I couldn't find one that answered my question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would help if you posted the error.

Comment: Are you using SOAP (a protocol), and trying to use it as a REST API? I can understand why, but if the API is SOAP, then forget about bypassing the `SoapClient` business, and embrace the horror that SOAP is

Comment: The error that is returned is: 'soap:Server-Server was unable to process request. --> incorrect or missing id parameter'. The API is SOAP unfortunately. I did not write it, just trying to connect and update information through it.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `SoapClient` constructor is `wsdl` location, which in your case is `http://www.four51.com/services/User.asmx?WSDL`:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.four51.com/services/User.asmx?WSDL");
```

To speed up your request, you should save it localy.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, but continue to receive the error, 'Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> incorrect or missing id parameter in userModel.php(288): SoapClient->__call('Save', Array) #1 userModel.php(288): SoapClient->Save(Array) #2 userModel->approvedMsg('22') #3 {main} thrown in userModel.php. Should I not be calling 'Save'?

Comment: @scatzz88 You are on the right track. Add `array('trace' => 1)` as second argument to `SoapClient` constructor and call `$client->__getLastResponse()` to debug. Maybe `UserInteropID` can't be empty?

Comment: So I changed     $client = new SoapClient("four51.com/services/User.asmx?WSDL", array('trace' => 1));     and also provided a UserInteropID and PhoneNumber, however am receiving the exact same error.

Comment: That error comes from the server. Your `$params` is correctly formated as far as I can tell. Maybe it doesn't like some supplied value. Difficult to say with such cryptic message.

Comment: Could it be something to do with needing to tell the SoapClient which version I want to use, 1.1 or 1.2? 1.2 allows for null strings I believe. The services allows for either one. http://www.four51.com/services/User.asmx?op=Save

Comment: I get the same result with `'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2` in `$options` parameter.